# Why can't I define inline functions inside Angular templates ? How else to do it?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 and is new to it. I wanted to invoke a small function for a button click. So I tried doing this (maybe bcos I come from a React background):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="(() => { console.log('hi') })()">
  Click Me
</button>
```

I used an IIFE for the `(click)` attribute. But it didn't work. Why does it not work, and is there any other way to declare an anonymous function and invoke it upon button click ?
What I actually want to do is assign a value like so: `(val) => { value = val }`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works fine if you just provide the expression you want Angular to evaluate. If you have a property on your component e.g. `value`, you can just use the following:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="value = 'hi'">
    Click Me
</button>
```

Angular essentially just calls the code that you provide as if it were inside a function (that's a big simplification, but works for your purposes).

Answer (score 3):

Just leaving this for future viewers:

I found [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-statements) which states that the supported syntax is limited (not every valid Javascript statement will be valid)

> Like template expressions, template statements use a language that looks like JavaScript. However, the parser for template statements differs from the parser for template expressions. In addition, the template statements parser specifically supports both basic assignment, =, and chaining expressions with semicolons, ;.
> The following JavaScript and template expression syntax is **not** allowed:
> new, increment and decrement operators, ++ and --
> operator assignment, such as += and -=
> the bitwise operators, such as | and &
> the pipe operator

Answer (score -8):

In Angular when ever you call any function it checks for that specific function in its component.ts file.

So for example when you calling console it will be looking for a object named console with log as a function in that object in the corresponding component.ts file so console will come undefined.

you can create a function named log in the component file and then call it in the template where ever you want.

component.ts

```
log(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

html template

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="log('message')">
```

Click Me

Comment: I thought it was clear in the question **without declaring a function inside component**

Comment: I can't see that so I tired giving a solution.