# how to pass an anonymous function to an Angular template

Tags: angular, angular-template

in Angular template, how to do something like that:

```
<div (click)="(()=>{})()"> click here </div>
```

or

```
<div (click)="(function(){})()"> click here </div>
```

instead of:

```
<div (click)="myfunction()"> click here </div>
```

and then defining `myfunction` in the component controller.

Comment: You'd better start with explaining why you need such a thing because I can't think of any benefit it brings here. And no you can't use anonymous functions in Angular templates because the template is technically a special syntax only recognize specific typescript expressions, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The code within the quotes is executed like a typescript function anyways, So you should just be able to code things as you need them. EX:

```
<button (click)="count = count + 1">Click me</button>
```

answered similarly here [Why can't I define inline functions inside Angular templates ? How else to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450337/why-cant-i-define-inline-functions-inside-angular-templates-how-else-to-do-it)